# How to know the 'controller' and 'action' from the request url?

Tags: controller, request, pylons, action

I want to log the controller and action when a request comes, so I write a `__before__` in the base controller:

```
 class BaseController:
     __before__(self):
          controller = get_controller(request)
          action = get_action(request)
          logger.log('%s - %s'%(controller, action))
```

But I don't know how to get the `controller` and `action` just from the `request`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 params = request.environ['pylons.routes_dict']
 print dir(params)
 #-> {'action':u'action', 'controller':u'controller'}
```